# Getting null value from model class which is bind with a json file

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, model-view-controller, model

I have a c# model class which I have bonded with a json file. I am using that c# model class but I am getting null values even though I have populated the json file with data.

C# model class

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

Json file

```
{ 
  "Id": "1",
  "Name": "Kazuma",
  "Age": 21,
  "CityName": "Tokyo",
  "ZipeCode": "123456",
  "CountryName": "Japan"
},
```

Asp.Net Core MVC Controller

```
public IActionResult Index(int? page, Models.UserInfo userInfo) 
{
    return DisplayListView(page, string.Empty, "Index", userInfo); // the "userinfo" is giving me null value
}
```

Comment: Do you want to populate the Json in UserInfo object?

Comment: @Imran I want to use the json(Which I am trying to bind in c# model to use in the controller) data in my controller and show it on the index page. That's the whole goal.

Comment: How are you calling the Index method?

Comment: where this method call and how pass the UerInfo object to the method

Comment: @vivekuna I am directly using using it in the view.

Comment: @LDS the method is called in the Controller and I am trying to pass the UserInfo as an argument in the "Index" method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert Json data to UserInfo object:

```
UserInfo userInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(s);
```

This data can be used in Index page.

Answer (score 0):

how you call the action Method ?
I tried that in Ajax then it worked .

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Index", "ControllerName")",
            data: { Id: "1",
                    Name: "Kazuma",
                    Age: 21,
                    CityName: "Tokyo",
                    ZipeCode: "123456",
                    CountryName: "Japan" },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
               ...//Do What you want
            }
        });
```